# Get all the documents in an ES index with python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to get all the Documents saved in a ES Index called: news (44908 Document)
and the save them in a DataFrame

but when running the script, I only get the first ten Documents.

This is my Code:

```
esClient = Elasticsearch()

response = esClient.search(index = 'news',
                                body = {},
                                )

#scrollId = response["_scroll_id"]
#print(scrollId)

esDocs = response["hits"]["hits"]
fields = {}
for num, doc in enumerate(esDocs):
    sourceData = doc["_source"]
    
    #response = esClient.scroll(scroll_id=scrollId, scroll = '1m')
    #scrollId = response['_scroll_id']
    #print(scrollId)
    
    for key, val in sourceData.items():
        
        if key == 'tags' or key == 'text' or key == 'title':
            
            try:
                fields[key] = np.append(fields[key], val)
            except KeyError:
                fields[key] = np.array([val])
        else:
            continue;

df = pd.DataFrame(fields)
```

I tried using `.scroll()` but it did't work. I still get only 10 first Documents.

I tried specifying the `size = number` as well, but it's not what i'm looking for...

This is my output Dataframe
[image: Dataframe output]

N.B: I am using Jupyter Notbook

Comment: I would suggest using [`es-pandas`](https://pypi.org/project/es-pandas/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to access Elasticsearch indices through a pandas DataFrame API I'd recommend [Eland](https://eland.readthedocs.io). Then you don't have to load all documents into memory necessarily to perform operations on them.

<disclosure: I'm the maintainer of Eland and employed by Elastic>

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify `size`, the number of documents you want to be returned

```py
esClient.search(index = 'news', body = {'size': 44908})
```

But that's too many documents, and it'll likely crash.